# object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.flink.test

Tags: apache-flink

I git clone flink code from github, and open it with Intellij Idea, I didn't do any configurations in IJ or in the code(I have already installed IJ scala plugin and installed scala sdk), I directly go to run the following two examples in Intellij Idea

I am able to run batch mode Word Count example successfully(The code is the class `org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount in flink-examples-batch_2.11` module).

But when I try to run the streaming Word Count example(The code is the class `org.apache.flink.streaming.scala.examples.wordcount.WordCount in flink-examples-streaming_2.11` module), I got a lot of compiling errors:

```
Error:(30, 30) object streaming is not a member of package org.apache.flink.test
import org.apache.flink.test.streaming.runtime.util.TestListResultSink
Error:(46, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(47, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(82, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(83, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(119, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(120, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[Int]
Error:(152, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(153, 30) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val lateResultSink = new TestListResultSink[(String, Int)]
Error:(196, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(197, 30) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val lateResultSink = new TestListResultSink[(String, Int)]
Error:(242, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(243, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(289, 26) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val resultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
Error:(290, 36) not found: type TestListResultSink
    val sideOutputResultSink = new TestListResultSink[String]
```

Comment: Could some one help take a look？ thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I search for `TestListResultSink` on GitHub.com, I find it [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/test/streaming/runtime/util/TestListResultSink.java). That shows me it's in the `flink-tests` module. Have you included that in your IntelliJ setup?

Comment: Thanks @kkrugler. Yes, I have the class, when I git clone the repo, all things are fetched in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually `got org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount` running in IntelliJ, but it wasn't easy. I tried a bunch of things, but I think this was the path that led to success:

1. checked out the release-1.7 branch (probably doesn't matter, but I wanted to be sure I was on a well-tested set of code)
2. built the whole project on the command line, via `mvn clean package -DskipTests`
3. did an Invalidate Caches / Restart in IntelliJ (I kept getting errors during Build Project in IntelliJ until I did this)
4. Build Project (in IntelliJ)
5. ran `org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount` and `org.apache.flink.streaming.scala.examples.wordcount.WordCount`

FWIW, the Flink binary releases come with jar files for some of the examples, which can be run against a cluster without having to compile anything. This is an easier way to get something running. Details are [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/batch/examples.html#running-an-example).

Comment: Thanks @David. I am also able to run `org.apache.flink.examples.scala.wordcount.WordCount` without any special setup after open the project in IJ. The problem I mentioned in the question is about running the streaming mode word count: `org.apache.flink.streaming.scala.examples.wordcount.WordCount`

Comment: Sorry I got my wires crossed, @Tom, but I'm also able to run org.apache.flink.streaming.scala.examples.wordcount.WordCount now that I've cleaned up and built the project as described above.

Answer (score 0):

try build your project, then run the wordcount example!

mvn clean package -DskipTests